# Blade view laravel ajuda

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

Tem alguma maneira de somar um count na blade. Pois na interação ele volta 1 1 0 0

```
  @forelse($surveys as $survey)

              <p> @forelse($survey->options as $option)
                    {{ $option->users->count()}}
                  @empty
                    Nenhum voto até o momento
                  @endforelse


      @empty

      @endforelse
```

No controller está assim

```
    public function index()
{

    $user = $this->user->find(auth()->user()->id);
    $surveys = Survey::whereHas('options', function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->where('user_id', '=', $user->id );
    })->get();


   return view("painel.usuario.index",compact('surveys'));
}
```

Uma survey tem varias options.
Uma option tem vários user.
Um user pode escolher váras options, mas de enquetes diferentes.
Uma option pertence apenas a uma sruvey.

saida
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso tem 2 votos. mas ele tras um a um. por cada option tem apenas um usuários

Comment: Oi fabio, por favor coloque mais informações na pergunta;
1. o que a variavel $survey tem?

Comment: a variavel survey tem varias opcoes e cada opcao pode ter varios usuarios

Comment: mas as opcoes pertence a apenas uma survey

Comment: o controller que retorna essa view está assim   $surveys = Survey::whereHas('options', function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('user_id', '=', $user->id );
        })->get();


       return view("painel.usuario.index",compact('surveys'));

Comment: Verifique um  relacionamento do tipo hasManyThrough https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: Funciona mesmo sendo pivo a tabela option_users ? Por que eu tentei, não deu certo.

Comment: Não é usado de uma para muitos, um para muitos ?

Comment: Oque são essas options?

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (count($records) === 1)
    I have one record!
@elseif (count($records) > 1)
    I have multiple records!
@else
    I don't have any records!
@endif
```

Comment: Ele continua trazendo um a um seprado, ja tinha feito isso.